# Dropdown list with Json data

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am getting data from a Json array and parsing it into a dropdown list, I managed to get the whole array into the dropdown, but I am trying to show just the name of the city, instead of the name and the description, if I delete the cities[i]['description', the dropdown won't work, here's my code:

```
<body>


    <select id="sel" onchange="show(this)">
        <option value="">-- Select --</option>
    </select>
    <div style="background-color:lightgray;color:white;margin-top:20px;">

    <p id="msg"></p>
  </div>
</body>

<script>
    function populateSelect() {
        // THE JSON ARRAY.

        var cities = [{
          "city": "London",
          "description":"London, the capital of England and the United Kingdom, is a 21st-century city with history stretching back to Roman times. At its centre stand the imposing Houses of Parliament, the iconic ‘Big Ben’ clock tower and Westminster Abbey, site of British monarch coronations. Across the Thames River, the London Eye observation wheel provides panoramic views of the South Bank cultural complex, and the entire city."
        },
        {
          "city": "New York",
          "description": "New York City comprises 5 boroughs sitting where the Hudson River meets the Atlantic Ocean. At its core is Manhattan, a densely populated borough that’s among the world’s major commercial, financial and cultural centers. Its iconic sites include skyscrapers such as the Empire State Building and sprawling Central Park. Broadway theater is staged in neon-lit Times Square"
        },
        {
          "city": "Rome",
          "description":"Rome, Italy’s capital, is a sprawling, cosmopolitan city with nearly 3,000 years of globally influential art, architecture and culture on display. Ancient ruins such as the Forum and the Colosseum evoke the power of the former Roman Empire. Vatican City, headquarters of the Roman Catholic Church, has St. Peter’s Basilica and the Vatican Museums, which house masterpieces such as Michelangelo’s Sistine Chapel frescoes."
        }];


        var ele = document.getElementById('sel');
        for (var i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
            // POPULATE SELECT ELEMENT WITH JSON.
            ele.innerHTML = ele.innerHTML +
                '<option value="' + cities[i]['city'] + '">' + cities[i]['description'] + '</option>';
        }
    }

    function show(ele) {
        // GET THE SELECTED VALUE FROM <select> ELEMENT AND SHOW IT.
        var msg = document.getElementById('msg');
        msg.innerHTML = ' <b>' + ele.value + '</b>' + ' <b>' + ele.options[ele.selectedIndex].text + '</b> </br>' ;

    }
    populateSelect();

</script>
```

Comment: why wont't work ? did you try  `<option value="' + cities[i]['city'] + '">' + cities[i]['city'] + '</option>`?

Comment: Tried already, it wont show anything if I do that

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just do:

```
'<option>' + cities[i]['city'] + '</option>';
```

if it's really what you want, lol.

Comment: It works, but when i click on the city, it should be displaying the description in the div, right now it shows only the City name in the div